# Unable to install mysql-connector-python with C Flags

Tags: python, mysql, pip

In my virtual environment, I am running this:

```
pip install --install-option="--with-mysql-capi=/usr/bin/mysql_config" https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz
```

I get the error:

```
    Collecting https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz
  Using cached https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for mysql-connector-python, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-connector-python ... error
    Complete output from command /home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-iDBnrD-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cWuFBz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/include/site/python2.7/mysql-connector-python --with-mysql-capi=/usr/bin/mysql_config:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-iDBnrD-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cWuFBz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/include/site/python2.7/mysql-connector-python --with-mysql-capi=/usr/bin/mysql_config" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-iDBnrD-build/
```

I have latest pip. There are few related questions in SO, but none of them resolve this issue. Is it possible to install mysql-connector-python this way via pip?